# Pure meaning about people

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, definition

> -Thinking about the school festival's concert makes me happy
>
> -You're so **pure**

What does "pure" means when we talk about people and what it means in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pure" is synonymous with "innocent", and in this context refers to the fact the person is made happy by something as simple and wholesome as a school concert.

The word "pure" can also mean "untainted" or "unspoiled", and it is sometimes said of people who are not so easily pleased by simple pleasures that they are "jaded", or bored from having experienced too much of something. Describing a person as "pure" also suggests that they have not become jaded, or spoiled by life.

Answer (score 0):

If your statements are in rapid succession to each other, more like a dialogue exchange, the **pure** would mean *free of immoral behavior or qualities; clean*.

I might as well be wrong. It more or less depends on the context of the situation, but also on the mindset of the person speaking to you. It could mean a pun.

[For more detailed view](https://www.yourdictionary.com/pure)